# ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property

Tags: android

While running the application on the emulator, I have got those errors. How can I solve it so that my program will be more reliable ?

error:

```
 01-16 11:06:49.211: E/SurfaceFlinger(37): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
01-16 11:06:49.760: E/Trace(1633): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
01-16 11:06:51.230: E/SurfaceFlinger(37): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
```

Comment: can you post the complete stack trace..

Comment: @Ramkiran what is the stack trace and where can I found it ?

Comment: in the logcat you have list of message. post those messages here

Comment: @Ramkiran system is now slow I will give them in a few seconds.

Comment: @Ramkiran I have reeditted.

Answer (score 17):

This has nothing to do with your application, it's just noise from the emulator. Check on a real device and you won't see this message anymore.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting this log message when had an icon in /res/drawable. I moved it into /res/drawable-hdpi and deleted /res/drawable and the log message went away.

Answer (score 0):

My emulator was in Airplane mode. When I turned that off and pressed "Open App Again", it somehow worked.