# Access denied finding property "ro.sf.lcd_density

Tags: java, android, android-studio

My program is running correctly, but this error is being displayed in the compiler. How to fix it?

No answer regarding this can be found on Google, I checked quite many times.

activity_main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <!-- username-->
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout

        android:id="@+id/username_TIL"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:elevation="2dp">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText

            android:id="@+id/username_TIET"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            android:hint="@string/username" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
    <!-- password-->
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout

        android:id="@+id/password_TIL"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/username_TIL">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText

            android:id="@+id/password_TIET"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            android:hint="password"/>

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
    <!-- confirmPassword-->
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout

        android:id="@+id/confirmPassword_TIL"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/password_TIL">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText

            android:id="@+id/confirmPassword_TIET"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            android:hint="@string/confirm_password"/>

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
    <!-- SignIn-->
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton

        android:id="@+id/signIn_BTN"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="@string/sign_in"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        app:cornerRadius="50dp"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/confirmPassword_TIL"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity has nothing in it - initialised

Manifest File also has nothing extra added to it. Any explanations towards why is this error occurring. Also one more error is being displayed.

```
E/InputTransport: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
```

Comment: check this link -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14355759/ro-sf-lcd-density-must-be-defined-as-a-build-property and yeah there is stuff in google....

Comment: nope this doesn't answer the querry

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but mine was because of screen density. You may need to revise your images or icons size if any in the drawable folder then generate a copy to following directories.

```
res/
  drawable-xxxhdpi/
    example.png
  drawable-xxhdpi/
    example.png
  drawable-xhdpi/
    example.png
  drawable-hdpi/
    example.png
  drawable-mdpi/
    example.png
```

For more info read [here](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities)

Comment: I have a lot of images should this be done on all of them?

Comment: Yes you should distribute a copy of all your images to those directories... Then the system will pick the correct one automatically based on the pixel density of the device your app is running on:

Answer (score 0):

To eliminate this error message, add the following line to the `build.prop` file located in the `/system` folder on the device:

```
ro.sf.lcd_density=160
```

This sets the display density to 160 dpi, which is the [lowest among currently supported devices](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities). You can adjust it to match the specific density of your device.

**Note:** You need to have root access to the device in order to edit the `build.prop` file. Since this can cause issues on some devices, it is to make a backup of the original file before making any changes.